# Incrementing to new row with gs_edit_cells once previous row is populated

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny

I'm making a shiny app that acts as a visitor counter. It takes user input from action buttons then updates a Googlesheet with a table of values (date,semester,game,count). I can populate the first value of the of the input, however I'm not quite sure how to "increment" `gs_edit_cells()` as it only lets me specify one specific anchor cell.

I've tried using `gs_add_row()`, however it doesn't agree with the dimensions of the input, as its say it needs to be of value 0? I've scoured here, as this seems like it should be a trivial issue to fix.

**Server:**

the variable data is of the form

`data <- c("date","semester","games","num")`

```
saveData <- function(data) {
  # Grab the google sheet
  table <- gs_title("Game_Table")

  show(data)
  gs_edit_cells(ss = table, 
                ws = 1, 
                input = data,
                anchor = "A1", 
                byrow = TRUE, 
                col_names = FALSE, 
                trim = TRUE)
}
```

The first cell of the table updates as expected:

`17905  Fall    Table Tennis    7`

but when I run it again, it overwrites the old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new rows with either `gs_add_row()` or `gs_edit_cells()`, but in both cases you previously must have added at least one row and the header (for example, with `gs_edit_cells()`). In your case, they didn't work for different reasons:

### 1. gs_add_row

The documentation of the function specifies that:

> At the moment, this function will only work in a sheet that has a proper header row of variable or column names and at least one pre-existing data row.

In your case, it didn't work probably because your spreadsheets didn't have a header. A solution is to create the first row and header information with `gs_edit_cells()` before you use `gs_add_row()`.

### 2. gs_edit_cells

You used `anchor = "A1"` in `gs_edit_cells()`, so every time the spreadsheets was updated from the cell A1 (consequently, overwriting your previous content). The solution is to read the current content of the spreadsheets to know the number of rows and specify the cell where you need to start the update without overwriting past content (keep in mind that the header populates one row in the spreadsheets).

Example code (with both solutions):

```
data <- data.frame(date = 17905, semester = "Fall", games = "Table Tennis", num = 7)
new_data <- data.frame(date = 17905, semester = "Fall", games = "Table Tennis", num = 7)

# Grab the google sheet
table <- gs_title("Game_Table")

# save first row of data with header (run only one time)
gs_edit_cells(ss = table, 
              ws = 1, 
              input = data,
              anchor = "A1", 
              byrow = TRUE, 
              trim = TRUE)

# solution 1: add new rows with gs_add_rows
table <- gs_title("Game_Table")
gs_add_row(ss = table, input = new_data)

# solution 2: add new rows with gs_edit_cells
table <- gs_title("Game_Table")
last_row <- nrow(gs_read(table))
gs_edit_cells(ss = table, 
              ws = 1, 
              input = new_data,
              anchor = paste0("A",last_row+2), 
              byrow = TRUE, 
              col_names = FALSE, 
              trim = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I inadvertently used your first solution, as well as I made a mistake naming the `gs_add_row()` input so now it adds fine! Now, I use `gs_edit_cells()` for the header. It works fine using the passed table's col names in creating the new header for the sheet, however If I'm looking at cell "A2" it will always be the most recent entry into the sheet, whereas every row below it will be all previous entries. Is there a way to make `gs_edit_cells()` incorporate using the table col names ONLY without updating cell A2 with the most recent entry?

Comment: Do you mean if it's possible to change only the header?

Comment: Yes(ish), I have: `gs_edit_cells(ss = sheet, ws = "2019", input = head(data, 5), anchor = "A1",byrow = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, trim = FALSE)` With this I create the header for the sheet as it takes the column names from the tibble passed into the function. However it also fills the cell below it A2 with the most recent entry every time. I would like for it to do so but with out filling the cell in and overwriting it. If there is a way to hide this beyond just hiding the row in via the sheet options I'm curious to find out, but it isn't very important you've answered my main problem already!